# Is it OK to attach only the junction box ground wire, or is it necessary to also attach ground wire from lamp fixture?

Tags: electrical

While installing a hanging ceiling lamp over my kitchen sink, the ground wire on the lamp broke below the mounting bracket nipple, making it impossible to attach to the junction box ground wire. Is it necessary to attach both grounding wires, or is it OK to attach only the junction box grounding wire to the grounding screw?

Comment: Is the fixture attached to a grounded metal box by conducting connections so that the exterior of the fixture (if metal) is grounded? I ask this to determine if there would be a shock hazard as currently connected. If the metal exterior is grounded, then there would not be an immediate safety issue. A separate question would be whether you should reconnect the ground wire, the answer to which is yes since the fixture only complies with code if the original ground connection is utilized.

Answer (score 2):

> **Is it necessary to attach both grounding wires, or is it OK to attach only the junction box grounding wire to the grounding screw?**

All the grounds must be connected together somehow. You can use a [pigtail](https://www.doityourself.com/stry/pigtail-wiring-basics) if necessary.